# Java copying files to a new path doesn´t work

Tags: java, file-io, objectinputstream

I have another question. Right now I am writing a little program, which runs on my pc and on my laptop. These two programs communicate with each other. I can write Strings (like a chat) and I want to send files. This little chat works, but the files are making problems right now. Which makes me a little bit wondering, because I got it already running some days ago. But now it isn't working (can't remember that I changed important things). Unfortunately I cant undo because Eclipse was already closed.

So I was looking for the mistake but I couldn't find it since hours. I hope you can help me.

Situation:

I choose a file at my pc/laptop and send it to my laptop/pc (I send the text [Strings] on the same way as the files and it works). The receiver shall save the file at a directory (targetPath - it is defined somewhere else in the code. It is a folder on my desktop). So I get the file as an Object from a "ObjectInputStream" and cast it as a "File":

```
 if(msg instanceof File){ //msg is the object I got from the ObjectInputStream
                        //its a file
                        model.copyFileTo((File) msg);
}
```

this is the method which makes trouble:

```
    public void copyFileTo(File file) throws IOException{
            System.out.println(file.getName());//this is just a test and it works. It prints out the name of the sended file
    if(targetPath.toFile().exists()){
        if(file.exists()){
            Path temp = Paths.get(targetPath+"/"+file.getName());
            if(!temp.toFile().exists()){
                Files.copy( file.toPath(), temp,  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                System.out.println("copied");
            }else{
                System.out.println("File already exists");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("File doesnt exists");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("targetPath doesnt exists!");
    }
}
```

I do not become an error, but it prints "File doesn't exists", so something at "if(file.exists())" goes wrong. If I cut this part out the program hangs up at Files.copy(...), which I know because it doesn't print out "copied".

Comment: "So I get the file as an Object from a `ObjectInputStream` and cast it as a `File`": Cast??? No casting needed. ObjectInputStream??? Why would you use that? --- A `File` represent the name of a file, not the *content*, and just use a plain `InputStream` to read *bytes*.

Comment: I thought I have to cast it because when i want to save it in a directory i need it as File.

Comment: `ObjectInputStream` is for de-serializing Java objects, and is very rarely used. --- A `File` object holds the *name* of the file. The content of a file is a `byte` array (if binary), or a `String` (if text).

Comment: But when I want to save it in the directory "Files.copy( file.toPath(), temp,  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);", I need it as File/Path. So I cast it after I get it from the InputStream. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the source system, you'd do something like this (Java 7):

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\MyFolder", "MyFile.bin");
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(path);
// send fileContent to target system
```

On the target system, you'd do:

```
// receive fileContent from source system
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Where\\To\\Store\\File", "MyFile.bin");
Files.write(path, fileContent);
```

In Java 6 or lower, you'd use a `File` object instead of the `Path` object and copy bytes yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I have not tried it yet but i will. Now I am sending this File as an Object from client A to the Server and from the Server to client B as object too. This sounds a way easier. Doesnt it work like I want it? And in case of yes why desnt it work?

Comment: Let me say it again: A `File` (or a `Path`) object stores the **path/name** of the file, **not** the content. If you serialize a `File` object and send it to another system where you de-serialize it, all you'd get is the file name.

Comment: Ok now I got it. I am trying to translate your solution to my code, this will take a while. Thanks a lot. I will write when I have managed. I am just wondering, because it runs already like I did it, but now it doesnt. I guess your suggestion is the best way

Comment: Ok the half is done. I can send files, but I need to know the name of the file or at least the type. I thought of combine your suggestion with mine. So I send the content and I send the name... (as i did it before) . Is this a good way or do you have a better solution? And thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice of Andreas

> On the source system, you'd do something like this (Java 7):

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\MyFolder", "MyFile.bin");
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(path);
// send fileContent to target system
```

> On the target system, you'd do:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Where\\To\\Store\\File", "MyFile.bin");
Files.write(path, fileContent);
```

> In Java 6 or lower, you'd use a File object instead of the Path object and copy bytes yourself.

I just want to write down my code for other people:

This part is called when i recived an input:

```
 if(msg instanceof Message){// Message is a self made class wich contains the byte[] as an object and the File/Path as an Object #
                        model.copyFileTo((byte[]) ((ChatMessage)msg).getMessage(), (File)((ChatMessage)msg).getName());
 }
```

the method:

```
    public void copyFileTo(byte[] bytes, File file) throws IOException{
    if(targetPath.toFile().exists()){
            Path temp = Paths.get(targetPath+"/"+file.getName());
            if(!temp.toFile().exists()){
                Files.write(temp, bytes);
                System.out.println("Wurde kopiert");
            }else{
                System.out.println("File already exists");
            }
    }else{
        System.out.println("targetPath doesnt exists!");
    }
}
```

Thanks to Andreas.